# How to set specific dhcp client by default for ifup command to use

Tags: linux, dhcp, petalinux, udhcpc

On my Linux machine, I have two DHCP clients installed: `udhcpc` and `dhcpcd`.

When I run `/sbin/ifup <interface_name>` `ifup` application uses `dhcpcd` client to request the IP, but I need to use `udhcpc`. Is there a way to specify the default DHCP client in some config files?

Comment: dhcpcd is ipv6 client udhcpc is client.

Comment: @SadaananthAnbucheliyan, `dhcpcd` support ipv6 and ipv4, but I don't understand how it would help to solve the problem.

Comment: Which distro are you using? If you are using Ubuntu, It has a default network module called NetworkManager. NetworkManager will start respective DHCP client based on NetworkManager.conf

Comment: If it is not a standard distro, You can read the script and find out where the DHCP client is getting started and modify the ifup script to run your DHCP client

Comment: If you are still not sure, grep for the config BOOTPROTO in the /etc/ folder. Modify the BOOTPROTO config to your DHCP.